# Save multiple inputs Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to save a data to my database coming from 2 inputs which has multiple values. The scenario is that after a product has been saved, data will be save to my another table with columns 'product_id','price','size'. How ever when I tried to run my code, only the first value is saved in the column 'size', the data in 'price' are fine.

```
<input name="fix_size[]">
<input name="fix_price[]">

 foreach($request->fix_price as $prc){

            $cprice = new ContainerPrice;
            $cprice->product_id = $id;
            $cprice->price = $prc;

            foreach($request->fix_size as $size){
                $cprice->size = $size;
            }

            $cprice->save();

        }
```

Comment: In your foreach loop you are constantly overriding the `$cprice->size` property. What exactly do you expect?

Comment: change $request->fixed_size to $request-> fix_size

Comment: I'm expecting to save the values of array from fixed_size to my 'size' columns. Thank you

Comment: sorry I have mistype my code it is $request->fix_size

Comment: @RenzchlerOxiño, So may want to try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, `fix_size` and `fix_price` are arrays.

You have to get the respective pairs of each `fix_size` and `fix_price`. So you have to monitor the index in the loop.

This is one of the possible solution in your problem:

```
$fix_sizes = $request->fix_size;
foreach($request->fix_price as $i => $prc){
    $cprice = new ContainerPrice;
    $cprice->product_id = $id;
    $cprice->price = $prc;
    $cprice->size = $fix_sizes[$i];

    $cprice->save();
}
```

I may suggest to you to master the basic principles of programming and learn to debug codes by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much @aceraven777 . Yes I will master the basic principles of programming, thank you for your advice. I will learn from this. Thank you guys for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
foreach($request->fix_price as $key => $prc) {
    $cprice = new ContainerPrice;

    $cprice->product_id = $id;
    $cprice->price = $prc;
    $cprice->size = $request->input('size')[$key];

    $cprice->save();

}
```

The problem you had is because you loop over all elements inside the main loop and keeping only the last element. In other words, in the `foreach` loop, you are constantly overriding the `$cprice->size` property with the last you find.

Now with this code you access the "size" which has the same index as your "price".

Comment: hello, I tried it but I'm getting error 'Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::input does not exist.'

Comment: Thank you @rap-2-h

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($request->fix_price as $prc){

            foreach($request->fixed_size as $size){
                $cprice = new ContainerPrice;
                $cprice->product_id = $id;
                $cprice->price = $prc;
                $cprice->size = $size;
                $cprice->save();
            }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried it and it works for column 'size'. But my column 'price' is now encountering the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav